# Hallwachs’ and Lenard’s Experiment: why is kinetic energy simply $KE_{max}=eV$ where V is the potential difference

Tags: energy, photons, energy-conservation, photoelectric-effect

Hallwachs’ and Lenard’s Experiment: why is kinetic energy simply $KE_{max}=eV$ where V is the potential difference?
As the photoelectron is usually ejected by light, why shouldn't it be $h(v-v_o)+eV$ where $v_o$ is the threshold frequency?I feel this should be the equation in order not to violate energy conservation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photoelectrons were **emitted**, ie left the metal plate, with a range of kinetic energies up to a maximum value which was measured by applying an electric field to slow the photoelectrons down, stop them and reverse their motion.
The photoelectrons with the highest kinetic energy required the largest electric field to stop them reaching a collecting electrode which was at a potential $V$ relative to the metal emitting the photoelectrons.
This corresponded to the maximum energy of the photoelectrons of $eV$.

The term $h(\nu-\nu_{\rm o})$ represents the maximum kinetic energy of the emitted photoelectrons thus, $h(\nu-\nu_{\rm o}) \color{red} = eV$, which equates the maximum kinetic energy of the emitted photoelectrons to the electric potential energy the photoelectrons with maximum energy have when reaching the collecting electrode.

Comment: I think that was pretty good feedback that you gave me. Thank you for the nice feedback, Stack Exchange.